# VBA EXCEL - Variable Password error when password's string is changed

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel workbook i've three sheets that i protect with a password.
I set the password as a constant in a module

```
Option Explicit
Public Const strPassword As String = "password"
```

Then i protect the sheets in ThisWorkbook at workbook open event

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets(1).Protect Password:=strPassword
Sheets(2).Protect Password:=strPassword
Sheets(3).Protect Password:=strPassword

End Sub
```

And then i use Protect/Unprotect methods in my subs, like this:

```
Sheets(1).Unprotect Password:=strPassword

[...]

Sheets(1).Protect Password:=strPassword
```

Everything is fine until i try to change the password using something else than "password", after the change i get an error for wrong password inserted.
I can't figure why this isn't working...

Comment: Were the sheets protected with the prior password, and now that you've changed the password, when you try to unprotect them, it's failing?  Make sure the sheets are unprotected first, and then change the password.

Comment: @tigeravatar correct, make that an answer

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't know why i didn't think about it...

Comment: FYI that `Public Const strPassword` declaration is visible in the object browser, even if you password-protect your VBA project. FWIW you should drop that `str` prefix, if a "password" isn't a string, I don't know what is. If you think *Systems Hungarian* notation has any kind of use, [please read this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/). Systems Hungarian is a lie, based on a misunderstanding of what a variable's "kind" (not "type") is. 30 years later, it needs to stop.